# Why a web element throws CypressError with TimedOut reason, only randomly?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

In my script, I am trying to locate and click one of the many document links, with this syntax:

```
cy.wait(3000); cy.get('a[href^="/articleDetail/"]').first().click();
```

I got this error:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element:
>   'a[href^="/articleDetail/"]  but never found it'

The issue is this happens only few times, not all the times. Like 3 out 5 times. How should I solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you able to see same Identifier (a[href^="/articleDetail/"]) in Selector Playground ? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html#Finding-Selectors  and here is other reference link : https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/selector-playground-api.html#Syntax

Answer (score 2):

Testing it via the Selector Playground (as N. suggested) is a good step. What you also can do is investigate screenshots which Cypress can make on failure. That shows the exact state of the application when the failure happened. That usually gives a good hint to the problem.

Besides that you can also try to set the wait to an absurt value like `10000`. If Cypress can find the element at that case, the application is slow and therefor Cypress is not waiting long enough.

Comment: Yes, it matched 10 elements  each one being a result. That is why before trying to click the result, I narrowed it with cy.get('locator').first().click();

Comment: I moved on to another approach of filtering the results, by selecting a selection radio box, but this time the first result can be clicked, but I ended up with another problem described by https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695

Answer (score 2):

For different reasons (internet speed, CPU, Memory, errors) your page could take longer to load or not load at all. As a good practice, your page should have a loading system, where it is shown until the page is completely rendered. This way you could have something like cy.get('your-loading-element').should('not.be.visible'), which will hold the next command while the loading is in place.

Waiting is not the right approach as you never know exactly how long it will take and raising the time will only delay your tests.

It is very important to think of your test in the same way a test analyst would execute them, because one of the steps would be to wait the page to be rendered.

Here is some good testing good practices: [UI test automation good practices](https://medium.com/@cbernardes/how-to-get-the-best-of-ui-test-automation-using-cypress-and-ci-continuous-integration-f9c5f056b364)